# Go to the line in a latex table cell

Tags: latex, cell

I'm trying to make a line break in a table cell with Latex. An idea?

```
\subsection{Critique }
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.2\linewidth}|p{0.4\linewidth}|p{0.4\linewidth}|}
    \endhead
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \textbf{Solutions existantes} & \textbf{Avantages} & \textbf{Inconvénients}\\
    \hline
    Le logiciel 1&- aaa : bbbb.
    - vvv: rrrr. 
    - eeee : rrrrr. & - Application : 
    * aaaaaaaaaaaa
    * ffffffff.
    * hhhh 
    - eeee.
```

Comment: You might want to ask this question to the [TeX Community](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

The solution is :

```
 \hline
  Some text &  \makecell{Some really \\ longer text}  & Text text text  \\
  \hline
```